# ionic 4 parse and extract html pages

Tags: angular, html, ionic4

I am using ionic 4 and I am trying to figure out a way to parse a specific html page from a web site. I would like to extract data from a specific table to the page and use the data to populate an array. I use the following code to access the html page. I found a lot of example to extract data from json but not much on html pages. I am using ionic-native/http to access the page. Here is my ts code. Please help

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page {
   requestObject: any = null;
    public items:any;

  constructor(public http: HTTP) {
      this.loadData();
  }

  loadData(){
     let data:Observable<any>;
     data = this.http.get('https://www.example.com',{},{});

     console.log('my data: ', data);
  }
}

table :
<table cellpadding="2"> 
<tbody>
<tr><td bgcolor="#efefef" colspan="3"> <p><strong>ABC:</strong></p> <p><strong></strong></p> </td></tr>
<tr> <td>ABC-1 </td> <td><a title="ABC-1" href="xxxxxxx" target="_blank">Play</a></td> <td><a href="xxxxx">yyyyy</a></td> </tr>
 ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract data from HTML pages, you will need a node module callled [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). I'm not sure if this can work with ionic or not but this is a pretty good library for extracting data out of HTML pages.

GitHub - cheeriojs/cheerio